# open a Qt widget form from the QMainwindow

Tags: qt

I am having a project with a Qwidget form and the Mainwindow form, this Qwidget form does not have it own class, but I want to call the form from the button click event of the Mainwindow.

I just cant figure out how I can make it work, any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "does not have it own class"? There should be one, ui-file only never makes it. As soon as you have that class, all that's left is creating an instance of it.

Comment: @MasterAler yea, that is if I created a Qt designer form class, but this is just Qt widget form file..

Comment: Okay, what is there, in that "qt widget form file"? If it is a ui-file, without any C++ class, that wont work. If it is something else, explain, please.

Comment: yea, it is just a .ui file ? I guess it wont work write..

Answer (score 0):

You can create user interfaces dynamically at runtime using QUiLoader class.
See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quiloader.html .

Maybe that's what you are looking for.